# boost iostreaming filter gets empty values

Tags: c++, boost-iostreams, streambuf

I tried to build a stream buffer for reading and writing char* using boost::iostreams:

```
class MemBuf : public std::streambuf
{
public:
  MemBuf(char* s, std::size_t n)
  {
      setg(s, s, (char*)s+ n);
  }
};
```

reading works fine:

```
char myreadBuff[100];
myreadBuff[0] = 'a';
MemBuf mb (myreadBuff, 100);
istream istr (&mb);
cout << istr;
```

but writing does not work:

```
char mywriteBuff[100];
MemBuf mb(mywriteBuff, 100);
ostream ostr($mb);

ostr << "hello world";

cout << mywriteBuff;
```

What is missing?

Thx

Comment: Try flushing your stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setg` sets the pointers for the read area; it has no effect on
writing.

The simplest solution is to use two different `streambuf`,
`MemBufIn` and `MemBufOut`: the first calls `setg`, and the
second `setp`.  If you want a bidirectional stream, or to
support seeking, it gets more complicated.